# Reviewer stats make me appear a suggested-edit-serial-approver

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, review-queues

Currently my Suggested Edit review stats say this:

> Tom Redfern has approved 420 edit suggestions and rejected 3 edit
>   suggestions

Now, being a grumpy old git, I reject LOADS of suggested edits, maybe even at least as many as I approve. WHAT is going on here??? And get off my lawn!

Comment: I believe this is the same core issue as the above-linked bug report, which has also been posted on Meta.SE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243910/incorrect-suggested-edit-review-count

Comment: @BradLarson, what use is marking as a duplicate when the other question has no answer ?

Comment: @JID, because it's a bug report for the same issue.